# Mostrar uma aplicação A dentro do fragment de outra aplicação B

Tags: android, android-fragment, intent

No meu aplicativo, quando o usuário clica em *Adicionar Contato* eu chamo o aplicativo de Contatos utilizando uma `Intent`.

Mas, ao invés disso, seria possível abrir um `Fragment` cujo conteúdo seria o aplicativo de Contatos em si, ou seja, mostrar a aplicação de contatos dentro do meu app?

Comment: Creio que não seja possível, só customizando sua própria `View`, trazendo apenas os contatos e exibindo-os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sem telefones "rootados":**

Infelizmente, não é possível exibir uma aplicação dentro de sua aplicação sem seu telefone possuir a permissão de admistrador (root), por que você somente pode interagir com outros aplicativos via `Intent`. Desde os desenvolvedores decidam como seus aplicativos devem reagir sobre `Intents` específicas, ciar algo dessa forma é quase impossível.

**Para telefones "rootados":**

1) Você pode exibir uma lista de todos os aplicativos instaldos, para isso:

```
getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

2) Se o usuário selecionar uma aplicação, você pode executa-la via `Intent` e **criar um `system overlay` para capturar todos os eventos de toques/teclas**. Você pode achar uma forma de fazer isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top/4482868#4482868). Armazene todos os eventos de x/y desses eventos.

3) Você pode **recriar os eventos** usando o [`MotionEvent#obtain`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867059/android-how-to-create-a-motionevent/5867158#5867158).

4) Agora vem a parte que você precisa de um aparelho com acesso `root` (a permissão [`INJECT_EVENTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INJECT_EVENTS)). Execute o app e **injete todos os eventos** para que sua macro seja executada. Exemplo:

```
Instrumentation mInstrumentation = new Instrumentation();
mInstrumentation.sendPointerSync(motionEvent);
```

Você pode achar mais informações sobre injeções [aqui](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.U4zRofl_u0c).

5) Se você precisar de ajuda para compilar sua aplicação, esses dois links irão te ajudar: [How to compile Android Application with system permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions) e [Android INJECT_EVENTS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383401/android-inject-events-permission)

**RESUMO:**

É possível exibir uma aplicação dentro da sua, porém a chance dos seus usuários possuírem um aparelho com acesso `root` é muito remoto, além de sua aplicação ser considerada como risco.

**Referência:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869037/app-inside-an-app